# Move grid hosting to dedicated?

Tags: vps, shared-hosting, dedicated-server

I have been using a [grid hosting solution](http://www.tsohost.co.uk/clustered-hosting.php) to host a site of mine for some time. it is a drupal site with reasonable traffic. I have a vps with the same host which provides 0.5GB of memcached, but other than that the VPS is not really used because I don't want to slow memcached.

Without giving away too many details about the project I am making a web api to go with this which will be running on 2 dedicated servers I have from http:// www.lcn.com/servers (sorry - only allowed 1 link despite 300 rep on stackoverflow)(1 DS1 and 1 DS2). I have found the performance of these to be pretty good, lowish ping and lots of uptime.

I could get another of the DS1 servers (quad 2.44GHz 2GB ram) and move away from the current grid/cloud setup.

My question is: Is it going to be a good idea to move to the mentioned dedicated server over the current config? as far as I can tell its going to be cheaper, but with better performance because I can have APC/lighttpd and a 100mb port to myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a hybrid setup or a performance cloud (grid).
Some of the performance requirements to satisfy your CMS suite may still be addressed given the appropriate solution.
Not sure if you are shopping around for hosting companies,
If you would like I can send you information on a managed cloud service with Infiniband interconnect, multi-tiered storage and westmere processors or a hybrid cloud.

Comment: My budget if fairly low -